# Create yellow div above the link if page address matches the link

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

I have a navigation bar with a unordered list and multiple items that contains links for the individual pages.

I want a yellow box to appear ontop of the link if i'm on that current page. I made the yellow boxes as you can see and i'm trying to think of the best approach for making the box appear on the concurrent page, any ideas?

[image]

Part i'm talking about:

```
const linkStyle = css`
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    color: ${theme.colors.text};
    &::after {
      background-color: ${theme.colors.primary};
      width: 150%;
      height: 40px;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      top: -50px;
      left: 50%;
   }
  `;
```

Full file Header.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";
import { useTheme } from "emotion-theming";

const Header = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const headerStyle = css`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  `;

  const navStyle = css`
    width: 1093px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: ${theme.colors["bg-nav"]};
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    height: 109px;
  `;
  const accountStyle = css`
    width: 428px;
    height: 109px;
    background-color: ${theme.colors["alt-red"]};
  `;

  const ulStyle = css`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
  `;

  const itemStyle = css`
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 30px;
  `;

  const linkStyle = css`
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Montserrat";
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    color: ${theme.colors.text};
    &::after {
      background-color: ${theme.colors.primary};
      width: 150%;
      height: 40px;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      top: -50px;
      left: 50%;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <header className={headerStyle}>
      <nav className={navStyle}>
        <ul className={ulStyle}>
          <li className={itemStyle}>
            <a className={linkStyle} href="/">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={itemStyle}>
            <a className={linkStyle} href="/">
              Menu
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={itemStyle}>
            <a className={linkStyle} href="/">
              Gallery
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={itemStyle}>
            <a className={linkStyle} href="/">
              Testiminials
            </a>
          </li>
          <li className={itemStyle}>
            <a className={linkStyle} href="/">
              Contact Us
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className={accountStyle}></div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: https://reactgo.com/reactrouter/navlink/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what library you are using for routing because each one does it differently. Assuming you are using the most popular (afaik) React Router library, then it would be a case of using a `<NavLink>` instead of a `<Link>`.  When the current URL matches the `<NavLink>` you can add a custom class to `activeClassName`.

Here’s a link to what I’m referring to: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom

With that in mind, here’s a simplified version of what you’d need to do:

```
import React from "react";
import { css } from "emotion";
import { useTheme } from "emotion-theming";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  const activeClass = css`
    /* active css styles go here */
  `;

  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink exact to="/" className={linkStyle} activeClassName={activeClass}>
              Home
            </NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/menu" className={linkStyle} activeClassName={activeClass}>
              Menu
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: This worked, i just needed to write exact in NavLink for it to work perfectly.

Comment: Ah you're right, just updated the snippet - as a side note: this would only apply to the home link - i.e. if the path is just `"/"`. You can obviously use the `exact` param for other cases, but it's commonly used for the home path.